# Как добавить подсветку в терминале?

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome

OS: Fedora 31 / GNOME

Как добавить подсветку для `[gefion@fedora ~]$` потому как, когда терминал заполняется, вся сливается в одну кучу и сложно ориентироваться[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стандартным способом через параметры терминала это сделать не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цвет и внешний вид приветствия задаются переменной PS1. Скорее всего у Вас не прилетел файлик `/etc/skel/.bash_profile` или `/etc/skel/.bashrc` при создании пользователя. Или федора отказалась от чвета в консоли.

Лучше настроить вручную

[https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash_(Русский)/Prompt_customization_(Русский)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)/Prompt_customization_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9))